# Send JSON data to PHP and use it to operate on MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

What i want to do: copy all selected rows from FIRST table and insert them into SECOND table. In json im sending event type ( insert or delete) and array of IDs rows to copy.
How i can acces to this JSON data in PHP file?

**JS:**

```
 var data_to_send = {
            event : "accept",
            ids : ids_to_accept,
        }
        console.log(ids_to_accept);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "request.php",             
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: data_to_send,
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log("Dodałem rekord!");
            },
        });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST["data"])){
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $ids_to_insert = array();
    $ids_to_insert = $data["ids"];

    $row_to_insert = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oczekujace WHERE ID='".$ids_to_insert[0]."'");
    $inser_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO zaakceptowane(nazwa) VALUES('".$row_to_insert['nazwa']."')");
}            
?>
```

**EDIT**

Ok, i fixed this. Just deleted contentType...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "request.php",
        //dataType : "json",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {data : data_to_send},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log("Dodałem rekord!");
        },
});
```

Comment: json_decode:http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode()` function. Its return php array which you can use to insert data in mysql. To read more about `json_decode()` visit this link.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: But if i put `$data = $_POST["data"]` before isset i got error: Notice: Undefined index: data in D:\xampp\htdocs\picturesoflight\akcept\request.php on line 4

Comment: debug your posted data using print_r($_POST) and paste it in comments.

Comment: `Array ( ) `  only this.

Comment: What is data_to_send? R u serializing your post request?

Comment: Everything looks fine, what u mean serializing?

Comment: How? Becouse even if i put single string to DATA, still cant see $_POST, also tried $_GET and its same.

Answer (score 0):

In AJAX use dataType: 'json',

```
var data_to_send = {
                event : "accept",
                ids : ids_to_accept,
            }
            console.log(ids_to_accept);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "request.php",  
                dataType: 'json',           
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: data_to_send,
                success: function(response){ 
                    console.log("Dodałem rekord!");
                },
            });
```

And in your PHP File use json_decode()

```
include_once("connect.php");
if($_POST){
    $data = json_decode($_POST);
    //manipulate $data
    $ids_to_insert = array();
    $ids_to_insert = $data["ids"];

    $row_to_insert = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM oczekujace WHERE ID='".$ids_to_insert[0]."'");
    $inser_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO zaakceptowane(nazwa) VALUES('".$row_to_insert['nazwa']."')");
}
```

It will work as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['data']` is undefined, because its not present in `data_to_send`.
You have to either access the posted elements directly in `$_POST`:

```
$event = $_POST["event"]);
$ids_to_insert = $_POST["ids"];
```

or you can change the JS part and provide the `data` element:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "request.php",
    data: {
        "data": data_to_send,
    },
    success: function(response){ 
        console.log("Dodałem rekord!");
    }
});
```

no need for `json_decode`, `jQuery` already converts the `data` object into a urlencoded parameter string, which PHP in turn converts into an array.

Comment: Doesn't work `$event = $_POST["event"])` and also changing to `data: {
        "data": data_to_send,
    },` dsnt work ;/

Comment: can you try it try this in your JS? `data: $.param(data_to_send)`